# Travel insurance for very short missed connection

Tags: insurance, short-connections, missed-flights

I'm taking a flight with only a 1 hour layover. Although it's one ticket with the same airline, missing the connection would cause big delays as the airline's next flight to the final destination is 48 hours later.

Most insurance plans I looked at for missed connections require at least a 3-hour delay to take effect. However in this case even a delay of 30 minutes would most likely mean missing the second flight. Are there any insurance plans that don't have a minimum delay time to be valid?

Comment: If your 30 minute missed connection means that you arrive 48 hours late, wouldn't that count as a 48-hour delay?  I've never heard of insurance covering only one segment of a multiple-segment flight.

Comment: @phoog I wonder if the insurer says they only cover a connection time of at least 3 hours since shorter connection times increase the risk of missed connections.

Comment: @user16259 that makes sense.  I checked one insurer's terms and it is clear that their "missed connection" coverage would not apply for connections of less than 3 hours.  David6881: Is that their next flight from *any* point of origin or just the next flight from your transfer airport?  When I've missed connections in the past, I've sometimes been re-routed through a different connecting airport.

Answer (score 1):

No, most insurance plans wouldn't cover that because you've chosen to take a tight connection.  It's highly probable you will miss the flight.  It's difficult to consider that in the rating process.

Some airlines (like Air Canada) sell insurance products of their own that insure against delays and the like.  These products are the ones with the highest probability of covering this situation.  Even then, it's not certain; you'd want to read the policy wordings carefully.

Personally, I'd recommend booking a set of flights with a longer connection.  If you originally had a longer connection, and the airline has rescheduled you, you should be able to rebook for free to something that will incur a lot less missed-connection risk.

Comment: If the connection time exceeds that set by the IATA for that connection, there is no valid reason why a travel insurance policy should deny the claim.